# Software Testing at the Earlier Stages of Development Cycle

Tags: testing, integration

I am trying to do a general research on software testing and writing an internal paper for my company. The purpose is to identify how the testing and verification stages can be reformed so that it saves cost in long-term. I know that s/w testing at the earlier rather than latter stages of a development cycle is a popular fix. My current understanding is the following:

1) Writing software tests earlier based on the requirements and acceptance criteria helps the s/w developers to identify integration problems involving any foreign components (e.g. third-party executables and binaries, etc.)

2) Improves s/w developers visibilty on the final product, acceptance, and the problem domain itself.

3) Easier to predict how the final product will meet the quality requirements.

If anyone would like to point out anything more obvious that I have missed in my initial understanding, I would be grateful. I have also found an article [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Rdh7n3_Gx4gJ:www.softwaretestingclass.com/why-testing-should-start-early-in-software-development-life-cycle/+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk)

**UPDATE**
I have foundt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797026/test-driven-development-book) and they to be good reading materials.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

One point made in the first article should be expanded upon, in light of the following management adage: Management gets what management monitors.

"Quality is built-in, not added on." is from the article. The same could be said for security, performance, reliability, reusability and portability, but, unlike quality, those can be tested for. If any of those attributes of a project are important for management, then they should be monitored from the get go.

In terms of project management, establishing your test scaffolding early also sets expectations of your project team early -- when you add stuff, you add regression tests for that stuff.

Parenthetical note about performance testing: It is important not to optimize too early. However, if you don't know what your baseline is, or even if that baseline is acceptable, then it is hard to make good decisions. A performance testing scaffold will allow you to identify what you have.

Answering the first comment:

I"m still not clear what you mean about third-party data. Do you mean something like mapping data, where someone supplies maps inside libraries? Another example is the release of postal code data in Canada.

Testing data requires a different mindset than testing code, or even testing configuration data, since those are well-structured, with relationships designed in. In the case of mapping data, you might be able to identify some known good map attributes, such as the distances between several points of interest and test for those values within some epsilon. This is a quality control check, much like you would make as a manufacturer when you receive subcomponents from OEMs to be integrated into your product.

The test scaffold can be seen as a QC acceptance test jig. In some senses, the test jig is even more important to set up, as you have less control over the supplied subcomponent.

Comment: @BobDagleish     Bob thanks for your answer. I am concerned how this affects integration tests involving third-party data in your designs. if you have a project where you are getting third-party data (or even customer data) in executable binary or other non-human readable code, your specification would require you to integrate that into the final product. Mostly, their source code is not available, NOT FOR FREE. This is a big trouble for a lot of s/w companies. Does it mean UATs should be designed in advance for those binaries in order to detect issues at earlier stages?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Model-Based Design as an approach to late stage testing or discovery of bugs late in the development process.  With Model-Based Design, you don't start with code.  Instead you develop models of your design and you verify and validate them in simulation.  Tests developed during this earlier phase can then be re-used later when you have code.

A variety of development processes and tasks can be used to check that the design has been functionally tested and verified during the early phase with models and simulations.  These include checking that the requirements are correct (i.e. not in conflict, are complete, etc.), confirming that the design model meets requirements, checking that the design passes all of the functional tests, and a variety additional checks to confirm that the design is free of bugs (from both a functional and robustness perspective).  This link on [verification, validation, and test](https://www.mathworks.com/solutions/verification-validation.html) has additional detail.